# Return Url not being passed in MVC login form

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a website where I'm adding authentication right now following this tutorial (http://benfoster.io/blog/aspnet-identity-stripped-bare-mvc-part-1) using ASP.NET Identity, Owin, etc... Currently instead of using html helpers and using the snippet below for the view, I have created my own custom form, but for some reason I don't think I'm passing the return url correctly because of which I get a 404 error. Can anyone please help me out? I'm a beginner in .NET MVC. Thanks in advance.

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
  @Html.EditorForModel()
  <p>
    <button type="submit">Log In</button>
  </p>
}
```

Model

```
public class LogInModel
{
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [HiddenInput]
    public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
[AllowAnonymous]
    public class AuthController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Auth
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult LogIn(string returnUrl)
        {
            var model = new LogInModel
            {
                ReturnUrl = returnUrl
            };

            return View(model);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult LogIn(LogInModel model)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View();
            }

            // Don't do this in production!
            if (model.Email == "admin@admin.com" && model.Password == "#G16#")
            {
                var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(new[] {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "Admin"),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, "Admin@Admin.com"),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Country, "USA")
            },
                    "ApplicationCookie");

                var ctx = Request.GetOwinContext();
                var authManager = ctx.Authentication;

                authManager.SignIn(identity);

                return Redirect(GetRedirectUrl(model.ReturnUrl));
            }

            // user authN failed
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid email or password");
            return View();
        }

        private string GetRedirectUrl(string returnUrl)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl) || !Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
            {
                return Url.Action("index", "home");
            }

            return returnUrl;
        }

        public ActionResult LogOut()
        {
            var ctx = Request.GetOwinContext();
            var authManager = ctx.Authentication;

            authManager.SignOut("ApplicationCookie");
            return RedirectToAction("index", "home");
        }
    }
```

View

```
    <div class="col-md-4" style="margin-top:200px;">
        @using (Html.BeginForm("LogInModel", "LogIn", FormMethod.Post, new { @class="form-horizontal" }))
        {
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="label label-default">Email Address</label>
                <div class="form-control">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control"})
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="label label-default">Password</label>
                <div class="form-control">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control" })
                </div>
            </div>

            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ReturnUrl)

            <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Log In</button>
        }
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using `Html.BeginForm` correctly.

Instead of:

```
Html.BeginForm("LogInModel", "LogIn", FormMethod.Post, new {})
```

It should be:

```
Html.BeginForm("LogIn", "Auth", FormMethod.Post, new {})
```

[Correct usage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.formextensions.beginform(v=vs.118).aspx?f=255&mspperror=-2147217396#Anchor_15):

```
Html.BeginForm("actionName", "controllerName", FormMethod.Post, new {})
```

Comment: Thank you. This works for me. But I have a question. Isn't my controllers name `AuthController` and not `Auth`? A little confused about how this works.

Comment: Yes it is, but it's the asp.net mvc default naming convention. The `ControllerFactory` automatically appends `Controller` at the end. You can, of course, override the default behaviour.